# Strategy to find preferred row in a set of fuzzy matched group of rows

Tags: database, algorithm, fuzzy

I'm looking for a algorithm/strategy/approach to find a preferred row which can be used as an identifier for a group. This group is a set of rows which are duplicates (fuzzy).

For example:

```
Table A
|    id    | group_id  |     title      |   total  |   target  |    review    | 
|:--------:|:---------:|:-------------: |:--------:|:---------:|:------------:|
|     1    |     1     | the bst title  |    NULL  |    100    |    NULL      |
|     2    |     1     | the best title |    20    |    NULL   |  a review    |
|     3    |     1     | best title     |    22    |    NULL   |awesome review|
```

The rows given above are in same group (`group_id=1`) due to fuzzy matching on the column `title`. I would like to choose a row (something I can display to the user) as the preferred row to identify this group. In the above example, I would prefer row with `id=3`.

Thank you

**UPDATE**

An idea that I have is

1. select column I want to use for identification
2. define rule for each selected column (e.g regular expression, length of characters)
3. assign weight to each selected column
4. if the column value satisfy the rule, then add weight else do not.
5. each row will get a score, one with highest score is the identifying row.

Suggestion?

Comment: I don't think this is a task for a database.  Can you even describe what the algorithm should be?

Comment: Why would "best title" be the preferred and how can you communicate that to your algorithm?  Is it based on their input or are you finding similar titles, grouping them, and determining the best one?

Comment: @GordonLinoff If we can do it using SQL, amazing. But I am looking for an algorithm. It is broad question. How will you identify a group which has been formed by clustering similar rows?

Comment: justiceorjustus If you were given this group in Table A which row would you choose? I choose `id=3` because in the `title` is kind of the same but the `review` column is better than `id=1` or `id=2`.

Comment: Would you judge your chosen row only on the column it is matched by, or by all columns? And if only the match column, what data-types might the match column have? Always a string?

Comment: You can choose any column(s) and the data-type of matched column(s) would be string.